# Validate form data and query params in one serializer in APIView in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for my web API. In my post API I need both the form data and the query params from the request and pass it to serializer for validation. To achieve this I am doing this:

```py
version = request.query_params.get('version', 'v1')
serializer = MySerializer(
            data=request.data, context={'version': version})
```

and in the serializer I am accessing it like this:

```py
version = serializers.CharField(required=False, default='v1')
```

and then accessing it in my `APIView` as:

```py
if serializer.is_valid():
    data = serializer.validated_data
    print("version: ", data['version'])
```

Even if I pass v2 as the query params it always prints v1. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```py
sent_data = {
    **request.data, 
    **request.query_params,
}
serializer = YourSerializer(data=sent_data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Or if you want to only pass `version` query param to serializer, you can do this:

```py
sent_data = {
    **request.data, 
    "version": request.query_params.get("version", "v1"),
}
serializer = YourSerializer(data=sent_data)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: Thank you! This does not work with form data though :(

Comment: as `drf` docs says: `request.data returns the parsed content of the request body. This is similar to the standard request.POST and request.FILES`  
But query params are in `request.query_params`. if your data is not parsed completely u need to check parsers in drf.